# Use NSString for statusItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, title, menuitem

I want to give my statusItem a title an it should change it's content. but if I declare a variable, there appears nothing in the menu bar.
My String in .h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> { 

NSString *myString;

}
```

With normal text everthing works : `@"text"` but when I do it like this .m:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];

[statusItem setTitle:myString];

[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
[statusItem setToolTip:@"my Tooltip"];
[statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

}
```

of course I gave the string some content.
Thanks in advance

Comment: But where do you initialize `myString`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `awakeFromNib` is called before `myString` is initialized.  This is why your string literal works but initializing with the variable does not.

You could try this since in your comment you allude to setting the title from outside the class.

(1) Change your ivar `NSString *myString` to a declared property: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;`

(2) Create an ivar for your status item: `NSStatusItem *_statusItem;` and initialize in `awakeFromNib` as your are doing but to this ivar.

(3) Create a custom setter for your `myString`:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString *)aString {
   _myString = aString;
   [_statusItem setTitle:aString];
}
```

If you don't need the `myString` for anything else, you can dispense with that and just implement a public method to set the `NSStatusItem` title.  Note:  it's possible that to create that status item, you may need some placeholder text for UI metrics.  Not certain.